# Заполнение формы удаленно

Tags: php

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть главная страничка, где есть поле чтобы указать число, но сама форма заполнения в личном кабинете - и это важно.

Мне нужно чтобы данные заполненные в форме в личном кабинете передались в input на главной и нажалась кнопка submit

Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а в чем смыл таких вывертов? почему нельзя передать сразу из личного кабинета, определенно тут нужны детали, если Ваша главная страница тоже php то открыв ее вы получаете все с сервера, а значит нет смысла гонять туда-сюда данные

Comment: Если можно сделать как я прошу, поделитесь знаниями

Comment: Надо посмотреть куда форма с главной отправляет данные (путь в action="") и туда же отправлять данные из ЛК. Не забыв при этом, присвоить их как значение для name поля INPUT с главной